# Implement Microsoft single sign on only in external network

Tags: c#, .net, azure, single-sign-on

I am creating a web application which will make use of the single sign on organisation login feature on .net mvc project.

If the user is on the network I want to allow them to use the application without signing in as i wold be able to get their username with windows authentication.

If external i want to redirect them to the single sign on so they can be authenticated.

However my issue is that even if they are on the network, the application prompts them to sign in. How can i avoid this?

Comment: If the workstations users are logged in to the same auth domain, then the usual auth dialog will only be shown once, the token will be maintained by the windows credential cache, only refreshed when it is needed. This is not normally an issue. Are you using Azure AD?

Comment: yes i am using azure AD

Comment: I use AzureAD and the internal and external auth flow is the same, except that internal users are more likely to have a valid token and so are less likely to be prompted to login again

Comment: Paraphrasing; if the remote party looks like they're on the same network, you want to return `HTTP 401` to trigger windows auth. Otherwise you need to redirect to AAD sign in?

Comment: I would probably try to do this at a dns level. If the user is using some public dns, they get one IP. If they query an internal dns server they get another IP. The internal IP tries windows auth, the external IP tries AAD. You might need to deploy the same app to two IIS sites.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users)

> Tenant administrators and developers often have requirements where an
> application must be restricted to a certain set of users. There are
> two ways to restrict an application to a certain set of users or
> security groups:
>
> - Developers can use popular authorization patterns like [***Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC)***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-implement-rbac-for-apps).
> - Tenant administrators and developers can use built-in feature of Azure
>   AD.

To implement authentication in your application  please refer this Microsoft Documentation:- [***Configure authentication in a sample web app by using Azure AD B2C***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app?tabs=visual-studio).